# Learning the syntax of files in C

Tags: c, file

I can't understand the syntax of writing in files in C.
I was requested in class to open a file named Numbers.txt and then print from 1 to 10 and each new line. I dont understand the syntax of it.
We use fopen,fwrite,fclose.

need help with understanding how to work with it.

Comment: Better to use `std::fstream`, much easier API.

Comment: were not supposed to use it

Comment: In that case I'm afraid you are in the course `C` instead of C++

Comment: I never liked the "Introduction to Not Learning C++" course.

Comment: @Eljay  ,  1) C++ is definitely not a good first programming course.  The student needs to learn to think in terms of algorithms and to successfully apply those algorithms  via a low level programming language C++ is not simple nor a low level language.  2) The C language does not have templates, so does not have any statements similar to: `std::fstream`

Comment: Please post a [mcve] showing what you have tried and describe how it does not do what you want.

Comment: stackoverflow is not a free code design/coding site.  Please post what you have tried and how it is not doing what you want

Answer (score 1):

You use a FILE to assign a file to something you can use. fopen opens a file depending on if the file exists or not.

```
FILE *pFile = fopen("Filename.foo","r");
```

This opens the file that is located in your project with the same filename. The 2nd parameter is the mode of the file — how you want to use it. [Here is a table of modes](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/).  You must always check the return value to ensure it is not NULL, indicating that the program was unable to open the file as requested.

You always want to close the file when you're done editing it by using fclose.

```
fclose(pFile);
```

fwrite is one way of writing to a file; fprintf and family are another. Basically think about it like you opened a text editor and typed something in the file. You need to create a buffer (a place to store the numbers), then write the numbers into the file. [Here is the reference for fwrite](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fwrite/?kw=fwrite). I can't do all of your homework.